# Static object: manage set method

Tags: c#, events, static, set, observablecollection

I have a static observableCollection.

It is updated from the UI, using a MVVM approach.

How can I understand when a mod is made? (I need to change the value of a boolean flag when a change is made)

This is my code:

```
public static event EventHandler serbatoiDisponibiliPerErogatoriChanged;
private static ObservableCollection<TabSerbatoi> p_serbatoiDisponibiliPerErogatori = new ObservableCollection<TabSerbatoi>();
public static ObservableCollection<TabSerbatoi> serbatoiDisponibiliPerErogatori
{
    get { return p_serbatoiDisponibiliPerErogatori; }
    set
    {
        p_serbatoiDisponibiliPerErogatori = value;
        if (serbatoiDisponibiliPerErogatoriChanged != null)
            serbatoiDisponibiliPerErogatoriChanged(null, EventArgs.Empty);
    }
}
```

I have also tried to match a function to the event serbatoiDisponibiliPerErogatoriChanged, but it is never called, because, with the debug, I have seen that it entes in the set method only at the init of the window.

The weird point is that the obeservableCollection is correctly updated, but it never passes in the set method.

How can I do it?

UPDATE:

with the mot's answer, I have done this:

```
void test(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    Debug.WriteLine("test");
}
```

and

```
serbatoiDisponibiliPerErogatori.CollectionChanged += test;
```

but, again, it is never called... it never enters in the "test" function.. why?

Comment: Have you tried hooking into the `CollectionChanged` event?

Comment: yes, but without entering in the set method, it never calls the event, I think. I have written myClass.serbatoiCollegatiPerErogatoriChanged += new EventHandler(test); and, obviously, defined test.

Comment: @BenRobinson sorry, I understand now that you meant the solution of the answer by mot :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the collection is not being set again, it is modified in the inside.
If you want to track added/removed elements INSIDE the collection, you can register to the `CollectionChanged` event.

```
serbatoiDisponibiliPerErogatori.CollectionChanged += MyEventHandler;
```

Comment: I have done like you suggest, but I have still some problem... code updated with the details. The core is the it doesn't enter in the collectionChanged event. Why?

Comment: Ok, sorty, now it works!! Dumbly, I was re-init the data in other place. thanks! :)